# Execute function on window resize when window is larger than 480 pixels

Tags: jquery, resize

**>> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/VzQvP/) <<**

I think the title is self explanatory. I don't know why this code is not working:

```
function toolTip() {
    var list = $("#readMoreUl");
    var links = list.children("li").children("a");
    var tooltips = links.children("span.tooltip");

    links.hover(function () {
        $(this).children("span.tooltip").fadeIn(350);
        },
    function () {
        $(this).children("span.tooltip").fadeOut(40);
        });    
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 480) {
            toolTip();
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

I also wondered: is my use of the last `.resize` call correct? Emulating an actual resize so the function gets called on `window ready`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, your code installs the tooltip handlers when the window is > 480 and every time that is detected, it installs it again (resulting in multiple event handlers).  And, if the window is sized smaller than 480, it never removes the tooltip event handlers.

I would suggest doing it this way which is much simpler:

```
function toolTip() {
    var list = $("#readMoreUl");
    var links = list.children("li").children("a");
    var tooltips = links.children("span.tooltip");
    var overlay = $("#overlay");

    links.hover(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 480) {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            $(this).children("span.tooltip").fadeIn(350);
            overlay.fadeIn(400);
        }
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children("span.tooltip").fadeOut(40);
        overlay.fadeOut(30);
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    });    
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    toolTip();
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yVCwS/
    ​

Comment: I don't understand why this works. When the window is resized to a dimension less than 480 pixels, no tooltip is shown on hover - as it should. But how comes the browser knows? I can't see any .resize function? So the script is not told that the window has been resized, right?

Comment: @BramVanroy - When you hover the mouse over a tooltip item, the hover code checks to see if the window is smaller than 480 wide.  If so, it does NOT pop up the tooltip (8th line of code).  It doesn't need to change anything when the window is resized.